# Controller side latitude and longitude in ASP.NET-MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to acquire latitude and longitude during user login. I know that I can get latitude and longitude on the client side by:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
            x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        }
        window.onload(getLocation());
    </script>
}

<div id="demo"></div>
```

then make it hidden part of a login form. Then pass it by submitting the form to the POST Login controller:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
```

Is it a good idea? Geolocation probably can be easily faked while passing it to the controller is there a way to achieve it by C# on a controller side?

Comment: what would a person have to gain by faking it? unless you're blocking access based on geographical location

Comment: based on lat / lon? not by like, the country they're in?

Comment: most resources i'm finding are suggesting doing this through javascript as it's a browser feature. maybe you'll just need to obfuscate the javascript that's doing this so it's harder to find? i'm not sure.

Comment: and still you'll need permission from the user to get his location

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get a user's precise location directly from the server side. Geolocation data is intended to help your site provide a better user experience based on the information they sent you. It should not be used for security purposes.

Comment: This discussion is probably relevant too: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30080/is-it-possible-to-restrict-portions-of-a-web-site-to-only-allow-access-based-on